# Eliminate file depending on date

Tags: php, unlink

I am trying to eliminate files from my server depending on the time they have been on it. For the moment I have got the following script, but no files are being delated even though they were uploaded on July:

```
$dir = opendir('uploads/tradsp/');
while($f = readdir($dir))
{

if((time()-filemtime('uploads/tradsp/'.$f) > 3600*24*4) and !(is_dir('uploads/tradsp/'.$f)))
unlink('uploads/tradsp/'.$f);
}
closedir($dir);
```

Do somebody find a mistake in the code?

thank you for your time

Comment: try debug. `echo time();echo filemtime('your_file'); $is_deleted = unlink('your_file'); echo $is_deleted;`

Comment: I tried it with absolute link, and it shows the following error: Warning: opendir(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /var/www/vhost/sienstranslation.com/home/html/ordenador/castellano/area_clientes/home.php on line 1940

Comment: Is the `unlink()` function called? What it returns? Maybe it's a permissions issue.

Comment: you are using cpanel right? ask the admin to set `allow_url_fopen = 1` on `php.ini` and `opendir()` is not executing you can see

Comment: Thank you so much @Riad, it worked

Answer (score 0):

There may be some error in your `if` condition. If you want to delete files of past months you can simply get the month of files and compare that with current month, like this:

```
$dir = opendir('uploads/tradsp/');
$filemonth = date("n",filemtime("uploads/tradsp/".$f));
$currentmonth = date('n');
while($f = readdir($dir))
{
if(($filemonth < $currentmonth) and !(is_dir('uploads/tradsp/'.$f))){
unlink('uploads/tradsp/'.$f);
}
}
closedir($dir);
```

This will remove all the files of lastmonth if you want to remove July month files you can also use condition `$filemonth == 7` in `if` statements.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Actually I want to delete files passed 5 days in the server

Comment: then you can simply find filedate and currrent date and if their diff is greater then 5 then unlik file